# How to apply a font to website through CSS

Tags: css, fonts

I'm trying to add a custom font to our website using CSS:

```
body {
   background: #999999 url("../images/pattern29.png");
   color: #ffffff;
   font: 14px/25px Verdana, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
```

But whenever I change the font it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what do you mean by change the font? Did you include it with `@font-face`?

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `@font-face` property to add your custom font

```
@font-face
{
    font-family:"YourFontName";
    src:url("yourfont.ttf"),
        url("yourfont.eot"); 
    /*etc etc*/     
    font-weight:normal;
    font-style:normal;
}
```

You can then use this font by using the font-family property on your html

```
body
{
    font-family:"YourFontName",Verdana/*etc*/;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need custom font try web fonts.CSS3 has @font-face that can load font to your web pages,
One helpful and interesting article about @font-face by Paul Irish : [Bulletproof @font-face Syntax](http://www.paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/).

@font-face example:

```
@font-face{
        font-family:MyFont;
        src:url(../font/MyFont.eot);
        src:local('?'),
            url(../font/MyFont.woff) format("woff"),
            url(../font/MyFont.otf) format("opentype"),
            url(../font/MyFont.ttf) format("Truetype"),
            url(../font/MyFont.svg#myfont) format("svg");
        }
body{
     font-family: "MyFont", Verdana, sans-serif; /* Font stack */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to embed the font with @font-face first, then you can use it in your css with font-family:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [FontSquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com). They have an @font-face generator that will format the fonts for you as we'll as write the CSS you need to include the font in your page.

You can also look at Google's web font API. Same deal, they make it a little easier by allowing you to just add a  tag.